# Executing select query for first time in Partition mode taking more than 10 minutes. (Ignite cluster with two nodes)

Tags: java, cluster-computing, ignite

I have created cluster with two nodes (one on local system and Another on different Machine ). After creating new table,  we are executing select query for first time , It is taking too much time to fetch data. (almost 10+ min)
Please find attachment my server xml configuration and below is  client configuration class . any suggestion to solve this problem, Thanks in advance.

Client Node Below:-

```
public static synchronized void init() {
             try {
                    Ignition.setClientMode(true);

                    DataStorageConfiguration storageCfg = new DataStorageConfiguration();
                    storageCfg.setWalMode(WALMode.BACKGROUND);

                    IgniteConfiguration cfg = new IgniteConfiguration();
                    cfg.setDataStorageConfiguration(storageCfg);
                    // Ignite Cluster changes
                    cfg.setPeerClassLoadingEnabled(true);
                    cfg.setRebalanceThreadPoolSize(4);
                    
                    TcpDiscoverySpi discoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
                    TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder ipFinder = new TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder();                  
                    ipFinder.setAddresses( Arrays.asList("XXX.XX.XX.XX:47500","XX.XX.XX.XX:47500"));
                    
                    
                    discoverySpi.setLocalPort(47500);
          

                                                         discoverySpi.setIpFinder(ipFinder).setJoinTimeout(30000);

                    TcpCommunicationSpi commSpi = new TcpCommunicationSpi();
             
                                                         commSpi.setConnectTimeout(30000).setLocalPort(48110);

                    // this timeout is used to reconnect client to server if server has
                    // failed/restarted
                  
             cfg.setClientFailureDetectionTimeout(43200000);

                    cfg.setDiscoverySpi(discoverySpi);
                    cfg.setCommunicationSpi(commSpi);

                    ignite = Ignition.start(cfg);
                    ignite.cluster().active(true);

                   ignite.cluster().baselineAutoAdjustEnabled(true);
                   ignite.cluster().baselineAutoAdjustTimeout(0);
                  
                     } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error("Error in starting ignite cluster", e);
             }
       }
```

XML Configuration for Server

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="peerClassLoadingEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
                                <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
                                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                                                   <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true" />
                                                <property name="maxSize" value="#{1L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                                                <property name="initialSize" value="#{1L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024}"/>
                                         <property name="metricsEnabled" value="true"/>   
                                        </bean>
                                </property>
                        </bean>
                </property>
               <!-- Explicitly configure TCP discovery SPI to provide list of initial nodes. -->
        <property name="discoverySpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
                <property name="localPort" value="47500"/>
                <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                        <property name="addresses">
                            <list>
                                <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                            <value>XX.XX.XX.XX:47500</value> 
                            <value>XX.XX.XX.XX:47500</value>  
                            </list>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="communicationSpi">
            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi">
                <property name="localPort" value="48110"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="clientConnectorConfiguration">
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.ClientConnectorConfiguration">
                          <property name="port" value="10801"/>
                        </bean>
        </property>
     </bean>
</beans>
```

Comment: What select query are you running and how complicated is it (Or in other words: How long would you expect it to take, are you just running a query to get a single value or 1million entries at once)? Does it only take that long when you execute it from a client, or is the execution time the same if you run the query purely on the server?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS it is join query which will return only 25 records only. i have provided affinity key while creating tables. it is taking 10+ minutes for only first time select query execution after that , it is taking very less time. (1-2 sec ).

Comment: Please provide the queries that you run. Also the schema of the tables that participate in the query and the amount of data in those tables would be nice to see to analyze the issue.

Comment: @Denis : apologies for late reply ,  when ever i am creating new cache and we are executing below query for first time , it is taking too much time. ``CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Coll_1599935220869 ( primary_id INTEGER,collection_id VARCHAR(20),client_id VARCHAR(20), id INTEGER, personname VARCHAR(250), cityid INTEGER,PRIMARY KEY(primary_id,CITYID))WITH "backups=1,affinity_key=CITYID , template=partitioned" ``    please suggest some points so that we can solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the "CREATE TABLE" statement. Could you also specify the amount of data in this table and the "SELECT" query that is slow?

Comment: @Denis : we are creating table with just 25 records only. please find below join query ``SELECT CITY.CITYNAME , CITY.ID AS ID_B , PERSON.PERSONNAME , PERSON.CITYID , PERSON.ID AS ID_A  FROM  (SELECT CITY.CITYNAME , CITY.ID FROM CITY ) AS CITY LEFT OUTER JOIN  (SELECT PERSON.PERSONNAME , PERSON.CITYID , PERSON.ID FROM PERSON ) AS PERSON  ON CITY.ID = PERSON.CITYID``

Comment: @Denis Same delay i have observed when we have ignite nodes started on different machine and then we are starting client. it is taking same time to start the client. (in this scenario we are not executing any query / creating table.) , it is default behavior of Ignite cluster ??

Comment: So, you're executing the query from a client node, and it's actually the node join that takes much time, not the query? Check the logs of the client node and see which step takes most time. You can post the logs to pastebin.com for example and send the link here so that we can check what's going on.

Comment: Also try decreasing the `clientFailureDetectionTimeout`. The current value is too huge. The default one is 30000.